# limiting shipping method if a specific product is selected

Tags: commerce

I am trying to limit a number of shipping methods (from 5 to 3) if a specific product is chosen and inserted into cart. What is the best method to do it (I am using drupal commerce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for how to add a condition to each of your shipping services for a specific product or two? Here's a quick animated gif that shows you the gist of what you want:

---

[image: add a sku condition]

---

1. Locate your shipping services
2. Click "edit component" to control which service needs to be hidden based on a particular product
3. Add a condition called "Order contains a particular product"
4. You would need to check the "Negate" checkbox before saving to "show all the things unless this product is on the order." Which sounds like what you are attempting.

Good luck!